# livewire array inputs how to fix?

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-livewire

my component livewire

```
 public $images = [];

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'images.*.name' => 'required|max:255',
        ];
    }
```

blade.php

```
            <div id="images">
                @foreach($images as $index => $image)
                    <div class="card" wire:key="image-field-{{$images[$index]['id']}}">
                        <img src="{{$images[$index]->original_url}}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{$images[$index]->name}}" />
                        <input type="text" name="item-{{$index}}-name" id="item.{{$index}}.name" wire:model="images.{{$index}}.name" />
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <button wire:click="changeImageName({{$image['id']}},{{$images[$index]['name']}})">Update</button>
                            {{$images[$index]->name}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
```

so wire:model="images.{{$index}}.name" not working, not changing after typing

and update will error

Uncaught SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

Answer (score 0):

Make function update fix my problem

```php
public function updated($name, $value)
{
    foreach($this->images as $image){
        $i = Image::find($image['id']);
        $i->name = $image['name'];
        $i->update();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding the multiple attribute in the input tag. and change the wire:model value to just have images

```html
<input type="text" ... wire:model='images' multiple />
```

I Hope that helps